# get version code in defaultConfig

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-productflavors

I have 2 flavors

```
 productFlavors {

    one{
        applicationId "com.test"
    }

    two{
        applicationId "com.test"
    }
}
```

defaultconfig looks like below:

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.test"
    multiDexEnabled true
    versionCode getCode(versionProps)
    versionName '10.1.8'
    minSdkVersion 18
    targetSdkVersion 23}
```

And getcode

```
def getCode(Properties versionProps) {
def name
    if (getCurrentFlavor().equals("one")) {
        name = versionProps['build.version.one'].toInteger()
    }
    else if (getCurrentFlavor().equals("two")) {
        name = versionProps['build.version.two'].toInteger()
    }
return name}
```

Version.prop file have 2 variable

```
build.version.one=203
build.version.two=101
```

Now when I normally run project from studio getCode() function return null.

```
def getCurrentFlavor() {
Gradle gradle = getGradle()
String tskReqStr = gradle.getStartParameter().getTaskRequests().toString()

Pattern pattern;

if (tskReqStr.contains("assemble"))
    pattern = Pattern.compile("assemble(\\w+)(Release|Debug)")
else
    pattern = Pattern.compile("generate(\\w+)(Release|Debug)")

Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(tskReqStr)

if (matcher.find()) {
    println matcher.group(1)
    return matcher.group(1)
} else {
    println "NO MATCH FOUND"
    return "";
}}
```

Comment: what's about getCurrentFlavor() ?

Comment: I have added getCurrentFlavor() function